# Tooltip sometimes not shown (depending on computer)

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

we encountered a strange problem with tooltips in WPF. In our C# program, a tooltip is shown for a button if the button is disabled. This works fine - on most computers. On one computer, however, we noticed that the tooltip is not shown at all, albeit using exactly the same .exe as on the other computers.

Is there any property of WPF tooltips we overlooked? Presently I have no idea as to the source of this behavior, since it works on most computers. Is it necessary to install a certain library, .NET version, VS20xx, so that the .exe will work properly?

The software is developed with VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

We would appreciate any idea to get a hold on this problem.

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried to show the tool-tip on any standard windows button , e.g., by going to "My Computer" and hovering on any of the buttons on the task-bar, this is needed to exclude if the tooltip has been disabled in windows itself, also what is different with this computer , is it the same OS as others.

Comment: Other tooltips are working fine. Even in the application, a tooltip connected to an image is working, but the tooltip of the button is not. The OS is the same for all PCs: Windows 7, SP1.

Comment: Update: It works properly after installing .NET 4.5. However, since several things were changed during this update, I am not sure if it really was the change of the .NET version that helped. If I find the time, I will downgrade to .NET 4.0 again to see if the problem comes back again.